# I need articles to use in a commercial project, what open content licenses will work?

Tags: html, website-design, template, photoshop

I'm designing some web templates, and I need to add some sample content in them, like articles and stuff. I was wondering where can I find such sample articles to include in the template demo? I don't want to use the usual Lorem Ipsum thing :)

The templates would be sold commercially, so I assume the I'll need to use only content that has a license which grants you the right to use it commercially.  I'm thinking that GPL licensed content could be appropriate.

I thought of [uncyclopedia](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com) but it's under creative commons which apparently lets you use their content only if you are using it for non-commercial purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPL doesn't forbid commercial usage. You "just" have to turn all your project with GPL license. With a LGPL component, this is not a problem.

Try to [look for articles under Creative Common licence without "Non-Commercial" clause](http://search.creativecommons.org/), like all Stack Exchange articles who are on [Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 Generic](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)! It's just have "Share-Alike" and "Attribution" clauses so you have to:

- keep this license for the content you pick
- attribute all the content you pick to Stack Exchange and it's author

Wikipedia also use a version of CC without a "Non-Commercial" clause: [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aText_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License)

[Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) is [a set of different licenses](http://creativecommons.org/about/licenses/), they are not all for "Non-Commercial" usage.